# How do I create a Install4J Installer able to run multiple instances at the same time?

Tags: install4j

I have created an installer which is able to install several applications (the user can choose what to install).

I would like to know if its possible to run multiple instances of the installer in the same machine at the same time, I couldn't find an option to enable this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "General Settings->Compiler Variables" step you can define the compiler variable

```
sys.ext.installerSingleInstance=false
```

Then the installer will not be in single instance mode.

Comment: Looks like this works (with a slight change)
"sys.ext.installerSingleInstance=false"

But I noticed that in a linux environment does not work (Red Hat)

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it in my answer. Indeed, as of 7.0.10 this is only supported for Windows installers. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this also works for Unix installers.